# Using ODBCDataReader, why can't I detect DBNull in a field using DBNull.Value.Equals or IsDBNull in vb.net? Deffinitely DBNull

Tags: vb.net, null, odbc, quickbooks, dbnull

The way I know it's deffintely DBNull is when I use String.IsNullOrEmpty it errors out with 'Cant convert type DBNull to type String'

I'm using an ODBCDataReader with the following ODBCCommand to transfer from a Quickbooks Desktop company file to a SQL database via LINQ; not sure if this is a quirk of ODBC or something as this is the first time I've used it:

```
SELECT id, string0, string1, string2, string3, int FROM Table1 WHERE (IsActive = 1)
```

To process the result I'm using:

```
IIf(IsDBNull(e(3)) Or IsNothing(e(3)), String.Empty, e(3))
```

The table I'm transfering to does not allow NULLs.

I've tried using Not and swapping the resulting options around, I've tried using Is Nothing and DBNull.Value.Equals() and of course, IsNullOrEmpty.  When I don't have IsNullOrEmpty in the statement I get a 'Cannot insert NULL into Table'  I've also tried swapping Or with OrElse.  As mentioned below I should be using OrElse anyway.

Now, with another table in the same company file this code works perfectly with DBNulls.  I copied the code directly and I've tried every combination of things I can think of.  What could possibly be wrong with this instance that would cause it to not recognize the field type?

If you can point me in the right direction, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

What has tripped you up is that the `Or` in VB.NET is base don the one in VB6, which did not short-circuit the logic:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/orelse-operator

Try this instead:

```
IIf(IsDBNull(e(3)) OrElse IsNothing(e(3)), String.Empty, e(3))
```

Comment: Ya, I forgot to add that.  That's one of the things I tried, but I will keep that in mind for the future.  I'll update post.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```vb
IIf(IsDBNull(e(3)) Or IsNothing(e(3)), String.Empty, e(3))
```

is garbage for so many reasons.

Cutting to the chase, `DBNull.ToString` returns an empty `String` so, if what you want is a `String` if one exists or an empty `String` for NULL then all you have to do is call `ToString`:

```vb
Dim str = myDataReader(columnIndex).ToString()
```

Ignoring that though, You should NEVER use `IIf`, `IsDBNull`, or `IsNothing` and, as has already been established, you should pretty much ALWAYS use `AndAlso` and `OrElse` rather than `And` and `Or`. The latter should only be used when you want to specifically avoid short-circuiting and, in that case, your code is probably bad for other reasons.

So, rather than the `IIf` function, which was garbage from the outset, you should use the `If` operator, which was introduced in VB 2008. There are various ways to check for `DBNull` and a data reader provides its own. There are also better ways to check for `Nothing` but it's pointless here anyway because you can never get `Nothing` from a database.

Let's say that you were using a numeric column rather than text and you wanted to use zero in place of NULL values. The correct way to write code like you had would be this:

```vb
Dim num = If(myDataReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex), 0, myDataReader.GetInt32(columnIndex))
```

Like I said, the data reader itself can tell you whether a column is NULL. The `If` operator is effectively generic, which means that the two possible return values must be the same type or one type must be derived from the other. In this example, both are type `Integer` so we're good. If you did want to throw in a pointless check for `Nothing` then that would look like this:

```vb
Dim num = If(myDataReader.IsDBNull(columnIndex) OrElse myDataReader(columnIndex) Is Nothing,
             0,
             myDataReader.GetInt32(columnIndex))
```